# Trying to reproduce cummax function manually (function with for loop)

Tags: r, function, for-loop

For the sake of an exercice, I have to recreate the `cummax` function in R using `function()` and a for loop. The `cummax` function calculates the cumulative maximum of its argument.

Thank you so much in advance

Here is what I tried to do until now:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,2,5,7,6,8,5)

my_cummax <- function(x) {
  for (i in x){
    if (x[i] >  lag(x[i])){
        print(x[i])
    } else {
        lag(x[i])
    }
}
}

my_cummax(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be as below:

```r
x <- c(1,2,3,2,5,7,6,8,5)

my_cummax <- function(x) {
  
  # preallocate the vector
  out <- vector(mode = typeof(x), length = length(x))
  # set the first element as current maximum
  cur_max <- x[1]
  
  for (i in seq_along(x)){
    
    # if x[i] is larger than the current maximum use x[i] and update both out[i] and cur_max
    if (x[i] > cur_max){
      out[i] <- cur_max <- x[i]
    # if x[i] is not larger than the current maximum use cur_max
    } else {
      out[i] <- cur_max
    }
  }
  out
}
my_cummax(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3 3 5 7 7 8 8

# compare to:
cummax(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3 3 5 7 7 8 8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a super good R programming exercise by implementing `cummax` yourself. Here are several implementations and we will see how different they behave in terms of the efficiency

```
# This is a baseline by the built-in `cummax` from R
f0 <- function(x) {
  cummax(x)
}

# for-loop version
f1 <- function(x) {
  for (k in 2:length(x)) {
    if (x[k] < x[k - 1]) {
      x[k] <- x[k - 1]
    }
  }
  x
}

# Recursive version
f2 <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 1) {
    return(x)
  }
  v <- Recall(x[1:(length(x) - 1)])
  c(v, max(v[length(v)], x[length(x)]))
}

# `Reduce` version 
f3 <- function(x) {
  Reduce(max, x, accumulate = TRUE)
}
```

---

## Benchmark

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1000)
microbenchmark(
  f0(x),
  f1(x),
  f2(x),
  f3(x),
  check = "identical"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 f0(x)    1.0    1.55   13.296    3.90    5.85   933.5   100
 f1(x)   85.7   94.65  108.294  101.65  111.60   172.2   100
 f2(x) 4653.7 5383.65 7777.812 5908.70 7019.50 81626.2   100
 f3(x)  479.0  532.00  642.451  561.70  693.60  1169.8   100
```